# Why selectionStart on input is not working in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  const dateOfBirthInput = document.getElementById("date-of-birth-input") as HTMLInputElement
  const dataLength = dateOfBirth.length
  dateOfBirthInput.selectionStart = dataLength
  dateOfBirthInput.selectionEnd = dataLength
}, [dateOfBirth])
```

Here I'm getting the input with getElementById, then I can't set selectionStart on the input.

While this code sets selectionStart and selectionEnd

```
const dateOfBirthOnClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const dataLength = dateOfBirth.length;
  (e.target as HTMLInputElement).selectionStart = dataLength;
  (e.target as HTMLInputElement).selectionEnd = dataLength
}
```

This code works, the previous doesn't, is this some kind of "When working with React you should not use Vanilla JS" bug.

Edit:

I'm sorry I added the id to the wrong element. It had to be the input.

```
<div id="date-of-birth-input">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: The ID doesn't seem to be on  the input

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation or reference to either `selectionStart` or `selectionEnd`.

However, there's a `setSelectionRange` method:

```
input.setSelectionRange(data.length, data.length)
```

When using react, there are not many cases that require you to directly query the dom. Maybe you wanted to use a ref to your input instead?

EDIT:

The docs for `setSelectionRange` also state this:

> Note that according to the [WHATWG forms spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#concept-input-apply) `selectionStart`, `selectionEnd` properties and `setSelectionRange` method apply only to inputs of types text, search, URL, tel and password.

Ergo, the Selection API is unavailable on `date` inputs for instance.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "dateOfBirthInput.setSelectionRange is not a function", I previously used this function, I just checked my old source code and it was working, now it doesn't want to.

Comment: Updated the answer with potential reason for it: using a date input

Answer (score 1):

In your useEffect, you're trying to set the selection on the `dateOfBirthInput` based on the `dateOfBirth` value. If the `dateOfBirth` value is not updated by the time your useEffect runs, it might lead to unexpected behavior.

In other code, in your `dateOfBirthOnClick` function, you're setting the selection directly based on the `e.target` (the input element) without relying on an external value like dateOfBirth. This approach is more reliable because it doesn't depend on the timing of state updates.

Consider using `useRef` too.

I believe the following code is a more valid and solid approach to the problem using React :

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function YourComponent({ dateOfBirth }) {
  const dateOfBirthInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const dateOfBirthInput = dateOfBirthInputRef.current;
    if (dateOfBirthInput) {
      const dataLength = dateOfBirth.length;
      dateOfBirthInput.selectionStart = dataLength;
      dateOfBirthInput.selectionEnd = dataLength;
    }
  }, [dateOfBirth]);

  return (
    <input
      id="date-of-birth-input"
      ref={dateOfBirthInputRef}
      type="text"
      value={dateOfBirth}
      onChange={(e) => {
        // Update the dateOfBirth value in your component's state here
      }}
    />
  );
}
```